# Difference between express router method call and module.export method call and app.use() call in node and expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, routes

i have **app.js** which have

```
var express = require('express');
var report = require('./routes/Report');

var app = express();

app.use('/api/appReport', report);

app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

i have **Report.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var reportDb = require('../db/ReportDB');

reportDb.test(function(res) {
});

router.get('/all', function(req, resp) {
    reportDb.getAll(function(result) {
        resp.status(200);
        resp.send(result);
        return resp;
    });

});
```

i have **ReportDB.js**

```
module.exports.test = function() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

module.exports.getAll = function (callback) {
    //Some operations
};
```

the above code are working fine.

**My question is**

when i start the node js server it is automatically calling reportDb.test() present in Report.js but it is not automatically calling router.get() present in Report.js.
so i want to know what is the difference on calling of test() and router.get() ?

i know when we hit '/all' url then it will call router.get().
but for reportDb.test() we are not calling in app.js, so how it is automatically calling at the time of server starting ?

let say if i use below function inside Report.js. then it'll not exicute.

```
function test1() {
    console.log('hello...');
}
```

i want to know is it app.use() calls all the method automatically which are exported ?

Comment: arent you explicitly calling your reportDB.test function from Report.js?

Comment: yes i am calling it from Report.js. but i am not calling it from app.js. so how it calls at the time of server starting time

Comment: i want to know about is it app.use() calls all the method automatically which are exported ?

Answer (score 0):

Its calling test() because you have written

```
    reportDb.test(function(res) {

    });
```

in report.js and included reportDb.js in it. Also you have included report.js in app.js.

```
    app.use('/api/appReport', report);
```

Its not that calling test()

Your router.get() will call when you will hit the url like localhost:3000/all

Comment: then if i use `function test() {
    console.log('hello...');
}` method inside Report.js then it'll not exicute. so what is the difference i want to know ?